# Solidity - Sort array of structs On-chain

Tags: solidity, blockchain, optimization

I have struct like this:

```
struct UserInfo {
    address wallet;
    uint256 points;
}
```

and array of this struct like this:

```
UserInfo[] private users;
```

Im trying to sort this array of users by their points. the problem is these users may become thousands or millions, so I cant fetch them and sort them off-chain and sorting them on-chain would use so much gas that transaction may get out of gas.

is there any solution that makes this possible ?

Comment: its depends on how often you sort them you can also check if you can reduce your uint to less bytes not 256 that would take less space on block chain .

Comment: Do you really need it to be sorted? What's the use case? If you really need them sorted perhaps a better option is to maintain a separate index, or keep them sorted using a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

Comment: yahoo5000: the space is not the problem, the big for is the real problem

Comment: Ismael: the use case that I want to sort my users based on their points, so they can achieve some governance in contract and it really should be done. and by the heap, how can I use such struct in solidity?

Comment: @Godfather Implementing a heap shouldn't be hard, you can start from here https://github.com/Dev43/heap-solidity. I don't understand why the order is important, sometimes it is easier to change the problem to workaround the blockchain limitations. In my experience keeping sorted an arbitrary large array will consume too much gas, so it is better to avoid it whenever it is possible.